# HTMX - Read URL Search Params / Query String and pass into fetch request

Tags: query-string, htmx, urlsearchparams

Very simple landing page, thought it would be a good place to start playing with HTMX. The objective is really simple:

Landing page with a query string in the URL. onLoad it fires a request to server, sending the params from the query string along. Server does its thing and sends back a success or error HTML snippet.

I do not need a button or form, all the info I need comes from the queryString. Users get redirected to this page from another app.

**Question 1:** How can I get the searchParms into the `hx-get`?

I must be missing something but I couldn't find any other way than using some JS.

HTMX:

```html
<div
  hx-get="https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users"
  hx-vals="js:{id: id, comment: comment}"
  hx-trigger="load"
  hx-target="#result"
></div>
<div id="result" class="m-8 p-8 bg-slate-200">Loading…</div>
```

JS:

```js
function getParams() {
  // const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
  const urlParams = new URLSearchParams('id=4&comment=25');
  const id = urlParams.get('id');
  const comment = urlParams.get('comment');

  return { id: id, comment: comment };
}

const { id, comment } = getParams();
```

Sample:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-9z2kgg?file=index.html

**Question 2:** I would have thought the entire idea behind HTMX was that for the very largest part I don't need to write the JS.
Or is this a case where I would look at Hyperscript?

**Question 3:** `hx-trigger="load"` on a div looks odd to me, surely that's not exactly how it's thought to be done?

In production I would of course do the entire parsing of the queryString and writing the HTML response in the backend - but for that I need to get the params from the queryString back there first. What am I missing?

Comment: The query string is already sent to the server when the page is first requested, why don’t you just do your thing then?! In any case, I doubt HTMX has features to work with the browser’s location built-in, but you can use [htmx.ajax()](https://htmx.org/api/#ajax) to send a custom request whose response will be handled by HTMX.

Comment: Thank you @BenderBoy!

As far as I can see the query string only gets to my endpoint if I either include it in the hx-get or append it through the hx-vals.

I cannot dynamically update the hx-get with query string from my URL, I can only update hx-vals.

Comment: Hm yeah, I figured you could modify the request url using HTMX’s event system, but it doesn’t seem possible. Still, if you already load the page with the query string, the server has already seen it. If you really want to send a request to the same url again, just async, you could do `hx-get=""`.

Comment: Thanks again @BenderBoy, appreciated your effort, I just posted a somewhat more elegant solution which I came across doing more digging and reading - took me a while but this is starting to make more sense now :)

Answer (score 1):

After digging into this I would like to present a more elegant solution:

HTMX adds additional headers to HTTP request headers. You can inspect these and tailor your response. In particular the `HX-Current-URL` is of interest here.

If you don't serve from or have access to your web server directly and interact with and/or have access to an endpoint you can read the request url from this additional header HTMX appends:

```js
const requestUrl = request.headers.get("HX-Current-URL")!;
```

And you can then extract the query string, in this example `id`:

```js
const postId = new URL(requestUrl).searchParams.get("id");
```

And then append the `id` to your fetch call, e.g.:

```js
const res = await fetch(
  `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${postId}`
);
```

This way on page load you can feed the query string variables from your current URL into a fetch call to any API.

```html
<div hx-get="/api/getPost" hx-trigger="load" hx-target="#result"></div>
<div id="result" class="m-8 p-8 bg-slate-200">Loading…</div>
```